# Update my database when I close a popup window that uses a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am new to `ASP.NET` and `C#`.

I would like to update my database depending on which row is selected in a GridView.

This GridView is used in a pop up window (another ASPX page).

The code behind of my pop up window is the following:

```
protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedID;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
        selectedID = (gvDetails.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        Session["IDs"] = selectedID;
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdUpdateSelectedRow = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update myTable Set Selected = " + 1 +
                      " WHERE Id = " + Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDs"]) + "", conn);
        cmdUpdateSelectedRow.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Close();
         gvr.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:window.close()");//i deleted the id= 
      }
 }
```

However, my database is never updated.

Is code in the `RowDataBound` method is running before or after the user selects a row?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you are going so wrong the event which is fired on selection of a row is `gvDetails_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: yes but I want to get the value of the first column, how can I achieve that using SelectedIndexChanged ?

Answer (score 0):

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, get the current selected row:

```
GridViewRow row = gvDetails.SelectedRow;
```

Then, update your database

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdUpdateSelectedRow = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update myTable Set Selected = " + row.Cells[0].Text +
" WHERE Id = " + Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDs"]) + "", conn);
```

The key to getting the data from the row's first column is this: row.Cells[0].Text